# Jsoup emits &quot; entity in text nodes

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to sanitize HTML coming from a TinyMCE control. The HTML being inserted may contain Velocity macros. Jsoup encodes double quotes in text nodes as `&quot;`, which breaks the Velocity templates. For example `#if ($foo=="bar")` is being changed to `#if ($foo=&quot;bar&quot;)`, which Velocity considers to be an error.

TinyMCE itself avoids this problem by only encoding quotes in attribute values. Quotes in text nodes are left unmolested.

So, is there some way to have Jsoup only encode quotes in attribute values and not in text nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Try Jsoup 1.8.1, it is not producing `&quot;` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

> `public boolean prettyPrint()`
>
> Get if pretty printing is enabled. Default is true. If disabled, the
>   HTML output methods will not re-format the output, and the output will
>   generally look like the input.

To tell JSoup not to re-format your document, you'd simply include

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

[JSoup API - Class Document.OutputSettings](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint%28boolean%29)

Comment: I've tried setting pretty print to `true` and escape mode to `xhtml` but it's still encoding quotes in text nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I tried pretty print `false`. Still no joy.

Comment: Could you please add some of your code and what source you're trying to parse?